# Display a huge BMP file

Tags: image, file, png, bmp

I currently have a 48 000 001 kB .BMP file on my SSD (it's a version of Mandelbrot's set in 128 kpx × 128 kpx) and I would like to display it. I have several choices : I convert it to .PNG or .JPEG, although I would prefer PNG, which is the most reasonable or I find a software strong enough to display it and let me freely move in as I can with a 40k × 40k .PNG version.

Do anyone have an idea to accomplish this huge task?

(I tried some converters but they didn't seem to work properly...

Comment: That would be 48 Gigabyte - or "jigobyte" as Doc would call it - which sounds about right for those dimensions. If it really is a simple lowly BMP, you could write a fairly trivial program in (insert favourite language here) to downsample it with a straightforward nearest neighbor algorithm down to a more reasonable size, so normal software can process further it as you wish.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to downscale it, I could perhaps cut it in several parts as you suggested then convert it but I am not sure I could get with several files a unique picture in which I can freely move, zoom in, zoom out...

Comment: Most Mandelbrot viewers don't store the entire image; instead they calculate the image for the window of interest, from scratch.  Ones I've looked at are pretty fast, and you can zoom a lot deeper into the set than a tile from a 128k by 128k image would provide.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use `stream` which is part of the ImageMagick suite to extract any part of it to PNG or JPEG or TIFF then maybe look at `libvips` and `DZSAVE` for deep-zooming.

Comment: Wouldn't constantly streaming data from the disk lead to a perceptible lag? I'm leaning towards (my other comment notwithstanding) a custom data format with this image tiled into reasonably sized squares. Each tile itself could be a PNG on its own, and in the concatenated data file an index could be written, with the size of each tile and offsets and lengths of the separate tiles. That way separate tiles can be loaded and unloaded on demand.

Comment: @Jongware I was suggesting `stream` as a low-memory footprint way of chopping the original massive image down into manageable chunks and then using a pyramid deep zoom type of approach to the viewing once the OP gets over the hurdle of the initial massive file size... so not constantly streaming from disk, just doing the initial dissection with the `stream` tool.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know anything about C or C++ or other, I only know Python and Caml as a math student...